# WPF bind enabled property of one control to a CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to bind the `IsEnabled` property of a control to the `IsChecked` property of a `CheckBox` using the following XAML, so the control will be enabled or disabled based on the `CheckBox` status.

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=aCheckBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

It doesn't work. What is wrong?

EDIT: thanks for all your comments! below is from style.xaml, now based on @Ivan's comment. The TextBlock is set to "gray out" when disabled (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852963/how-to-disable-textblock))

```
<Style x:Key="printCkBox" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="fileInfoTxtBlkBase" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding ElementName=printCkBox, Path=IsChecked, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="filenameTxtBlk" BasedOn="{StaticResource fileInfoTxtBlkBase}" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099402/wpf-element-databinding-for-isenabled-but-for-false

Comment: are you sure your binding can see "aCheckBox" ?? can you provice more code as we can see aCheckBox ??

Comment: As you are posing a `Setter`: Can I see the definition of the Style?

Comment: hm, it looks like it should work. I created the sample app and the following code working fine:
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox x:Name="TestCheckBox"/>
        <TextBox Width="100" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=TestCheckBox, Path=IsChecked, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>
    </StackPanel>

Comment: thanks! just added style.

Answer (score 7):

Though it's an old question, but still here's an answer to the *original question in the **title*** for someone else, stumbling here like I did:

```
<DockPanel>
        <CheckBox x:Name="CbxAgree" Content="Agreed" FontSize="21" 
                  Background="Black" Foreground="Black"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8 4 16 4"
                  IsChecked="True" />

        <Button VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Background="White" Foreground="Black" 
                Content="Submit"  FontSize="22"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=CbxAgree, Path=IsChecked}"/>
</DockPanel>
```